# Xcode 6.1.1 xctest release

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I create a new project and set (run) build configuration release,the issue.

This is my code.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface testTests : XCTestCase

@end

@implementation testTests

- (void)testExample {
  ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
  XCTAssertNotNil(vc);
}

@end
```

issue

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in testTests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: make sure in targets under tests -> Build Phases XCTest.framework not be in red color.

Comment: Xcode 6.1 default Enable Modules(C and Objective-c) YES,so there no need XCTest.framework. When "build configuration" debug it can run just release can't run.

Answer (score 0):

Oups, sorry… You are missing a link to the CoreFoundation framework!

```
LIBS += CoreFoundation
```